# (Android) Seems like my JSON query is getting double encode

Tags: android, json, uri, http-get

I am getting some weird errors with my Android App. It appears that this code is double encoding the JSON string. What should be sent is ?{"email":"asdf@asdf.com","password":"asdf"}
or 
?%7B%22email%22:%22.....

what the server is seeing is %257B%2522email%2522:%2522 ....
which means the server sees  %7B%22email%22:%22 .....

This confuses the server.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thank you for your help

//edited to define objects better

Code:

```
        DefaultHttpClient c = new DefaultHttpClient();
        if(cookies!=null)
            c.setCookieStore(cookies);

        JSONObject jso = new JSONObject():

        if(loginNotLogout){
            jso.put("email", "email@email.com");
            jso.put("password", "PassW0RD");
        }

        URI u = null;
        if(loginNotLogout)
            u= new URI("HTTP","www.website.com","/UserService",jso.toString(),"");

        else
            u= new URI("HTTP","www.website.com","/UserService",jso.toString(),"");

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(u);

        HttpResponse response = c.execute(httpget);
        ret.jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Answer (score 0):

what is `userData` ?

are you getting values from any EditText?

will using `getText().toString()` with the text from EditText help?

Comment: userData is a collection of strings that describe the user. Yes, the values in userData are generated by EditText but those or cleaned up in some other code. I missed the fact that jso is a JSONObject.

Comment: Can you print the whole JSON it is generating, ?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, dropping the "www." from the authority field in the URI constructor caused the address string to be encoded correctly.

I am no web expert, but if anyone can explain this I am all ears.   or eyes in this case.

--
Andrew